# View other users profil without editing their posts

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

So I want that user view other user profil, and their posts without editing them. I know that I need a username or user id as argument and pass it in the index.html but I don't know how to do it and I have some trouble doing it.

In the view I have something like this:

```
def Profil(request):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'blog/visitor.html')
    else:
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return render(request, 'blog/profil.html', {'posts': posts})
```

And here the index.html where a user click on another user to view his profil.

```
 <a href="{% url 'blog:profil' %}">{{post.user.username }}</a>
```

And my url.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^profil/$',  views.Profil, name = 'profil')
```

Thanks !

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: For now, it's static I mean in the url there is no user_id or anything I know I need to add it but don't know how